# What is cephalostatic theory?

Tags: human-biology

I just came across this theory while solving problems. I looked for it all over Google but couldn't find the actual theory. I guess I can learn it here.

Comment: Name the book in which you found that term pls.

Comment: The exact term "cephalostatic theory" apparently does not occur in any results indexed by Google (at least, until they index this question):
 https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="cephalostatic+theory". This makes it even more important to know where you came across it, but also are you sure you've gt the right term?

Answer (score 0):

A cephalostat is head holding device used in orthodontic analysis; cephalometric analysis being the clinical application of cephalometry - the analysis of dental and skeletal relationships of the human skull.

Cephalostatic theory then, I would assume, is the body of work regarding that relationship.